# How to set/format HTTP headers by simply writing Strings to a socket

Tags: java, http

Just using the core Java API I am trying to send a response with correctly formatted HTTP headers. With my current code, I can see the client recieves my response, but I think I am not including all the information because when I a return a 404 error to a web browser client the web browser just displays a blank page. If I try with curl, I also do not see a curl letting me know about the error. Here is what I am currently doing with the response:

outputStream.write("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found".getBytes());

Answer (score 5):

An HTTP response is made up of three parts

1. The initial status line, which is what you are sending
2. The Response Header (with response headers like `Content-Type`, `Content-Length`, `Last-Modified`, `Cookie`, etc)
3. The Response Body - (The actual HTML with user-friendly content that tells the user what happened.

You are only sending the first.

An example of what you should be sending is

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Fri, 18 Aug 2012 13:24:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/HTML
Content-Length: 90

<html><head><title>Page not found</title></head><body>The page was not found.</body></html>
```

Also, don't forget to close the socket at the end.

[This page](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/) describes the HTTP response in an easy way to understand.

**EDIT**

It's important to note that each line in the response must be separated by both the `CR` and `LF` characters. So you should also be writing \r\n to represent each newline before your call to `getBytes()`.

Comment: +1: Good explanation.  But he probably does want "404 Not Found" rather than the "200 OK" you show in your example.

Comment: Not true, according to [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html) only the status line and CRLF are required.

Comment: You should put a Content-Length header in too, or else the browser will not know how many characters to read.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz Not required, but it's what you need to do if you want to control the message the user sees.

Comment: @user1536486 Yes, I was being lazy :)

Answer (score 2):

When you have are giving a 404 error, you should include content for the browser to display. Include a Content-Length and Content-Type property, and then some html content for the browser to display. Also remember to flush the stream after writing to it. A proper response might look like this:

```
String response = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n" +
    "Content-Length: 22\r\n" +
    "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n" +
    "<h1>404 Not Found</h1>";
outputStream.write(response.getBytes());
outputStream.flush();
```

There should be a carriage return and a line feed(\r\n) after each header, and two \r\n's after the headers are done so you can indicate that the content is coming up.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a newline and closing the connection helps my browser and `curl` to understand the response:

```
outputStream.write("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n".getBytes());
outputStream.close();
```

...and a minimal "working" response:

```
outputStream.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\nHello, world!".getBytes())
outputStream.close()
```

Comment: Ooh, forgot to mention about the newlines!